# Returning date and duration based on task in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that includes time (in hours), task, and date. I want to create graph for each task on the time I spend on each task each day. I was wondering how to extract the data out of a data frame like this. I would like to make time-series plots across days, with each one having a different task.

```
Date          Task     Time
11/21/2020   task1     2
11/21/2020   task1     5
11/21/2020   task2     5
11/21/2020   task3    .5
11/21/2020   task5     1
11/22/2020   task3     1
11/22/2020   task4     2
```

Comment: Lets try `df.groupby(['Date','Task'])['Time'].sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: How do I mark this as solved so you get credit?

Comment: You dont need to. It is a question I have earned credit for before. Keep coding